# Merge two different product and run based on conditions

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am new to ios and i have not worked stuff as below.

I have two different products in iOS.

One is **APP A** which is prepared using Xcode project **A.xcodeproj** and other one is **APP B** which is prepared using Xcode project **B.xcodeproj**. Project A is built using NIBS and Project B is built using Storyboard. Both have different functionalities.

Now i need single **APP A**, which is combination of **A & B** means Two projects in single bundle and i will upload single product on App Store. When i am in Office and runs APP it automatically runs APP A means all functionality of APP A and when i am at home it runs APP B means all functionality of APP B.

Is it possible to do like this ? OR how can i achieve this gold.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check condition at the start of the application and run proper initial screen. If your apps are completely different it wouldn't create any issue.

Comment: Shall i have to merge both apps code in single Xcode project ? then at  app start up i have to check location and based on location i can set my initial screen . Is this correct what i have understood ?

Comment: "Yes" is an answer for both questions.

Comment: Thanks for support.One more question,Is it possible without merging both projects code ? Create single bundle merging both projects ?